# What is the license on SE's legal documents?

Tags: support, legal, licensing, copyright

I know the SE site/design is copyrighted and the user content has a "attribution required" sharing license:

[image]

But what is the license for SE's legal text?

- https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service
- https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use
- https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy
- https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy
- https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

Comment: Legal documents aren't expected to be published under a license. No license => the author retains all rights to the document.

Comment: Can you tell us about your motivation for asking?  Why is it important to know?

Comment: Well, most staff are users, and they contributed it to the site, so I guess it's safe to assume CC-BY-SA, right? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service, Section 2: Network Content](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#2NetworkContent):

> **All materials displayed or performed on the Network, including, but not limited to text,** graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and animations (collectively, “Content”) (**other than Content posted by Subscriber** (“Subscriber Content”)) are the property of Stack Exchange and/or third parties and **are protected by United States and international copyright laws.**

<sup>*[emphasis mine]*</sup>

So the text of the agreements, policies, licenses, etc are covered under US and international Copyright law as applicable.

Comment: That doesn’t directly answer the question of what license the text falls under though (which I would assume is “none”)

Comment: @Cai There is no license unless you've been granted one explicitly. You can read the complete terms in the section I linked above, but essentially  "expressly prohibited without prior written permission from Stack Exchange".

Comment: sure, that’s my point. The question isn’t “is the text copyrighted?”, it’s “is the text licensed?”. Copyright is automatic, licenses need to be explicitly granted.